# Convert Pixel Values to Coordinates - Python

Tags: python, image, coordinates, gis, pixel

I have a set of pixel values in the format of lower left (x1y1) (e.g. 204.55, 196.33) and upper right (x2y2) (e.g. 314.56, 294.77), and need to convert these values to their corresponding coordinates in an image.  The pixel values are not 0-255 RGB values, but the locations of the pixels themselves in the image.  I do not have the corresponding GeoTIFF to compare or to use GDAL/Rasterio to perform the conversion, but I would imagine there should be a somewhat straightforward way to do this that I cannot seem to find.

Is there a convenient Python library or recommended transform to use?  Any assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "coordinates in pixel space" and "coordinates in an image"?

Comment: @Marat - Apologies for the confusing wording, I edited my original question.  I meant to just state that the pixel values are of their location in the image and not the 0-255 RGB values.  Any insights on this issue are most appreciated!

Comment: to recover geo coordinates from pixel coordinates, you need to have anchors in some system (at least 4, more is better). Even still, establishing a translation that would minimize the recovery error is a non-trivial task. I'm sure somebody did this already, but I can't name a library out of the top of my head

Comment: @Marat - Thanks for the insights.  In my original dataset, I have multiple data points but I listed just the sample data point above to illustrate the concept.  I would imagine there should be some library that would enable this and I have some ideas, but nothing that seems to be the clear cut solution from what I'm finding.

Comment: what I am saying, the data listed above is not enough. You need geo coordinates for at least a few points. Or, I dramatically misunderstood the question - honestly the wording is hella confusing

Comment: @Marat - Apologies again for any confusion.  In short, for a given pixel value (x1y1) I need to determine how to convert that value to its corresponding coordinate in an image.  This seems similar to what I need, I just need to further validate (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499937/pixels-to-coordinates)

Comment: Sorry, I was thrown off by mentions of GDAL, geoTIFF and gis. Do you want to produce 3-tupes (x, y, value) out of an image? What's the input format?

Comment: You question remains not very clear; you might want to edit it and clarify it; adding some graphics like those in the linked questions might help a lot, as would rephrasing your question.

Comment: GeoTiff coordinate mappings are linear transformations, so if all you have is two coordinate mappings, you'll still need to know the image dimensions before you can map pixel coordinates to world coordinates and vice versa. If you _have_ that information, then it's just a linear interpolation between minx/maxx and miny/maxy.